# Umbraco umbracoReservedPaths not taking effect

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I'm trying to create a custom static page on a domain that has a Umbraco site, something like -

www.myumbracosite.com/test/test.txt

After Googling it seems umbracoReservedPaths in Web.config is the property I want update - https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Config/webconfig/ - however after updating to

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/test/" />
```

I get the following  -

Page not found

No umbraco document matches the url '/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2ftest%2ftest.txt'.

This page can be replaced with a custom 404. Check the documentation for "custom 404".

Comment: It looks like it's trying to log you in first. The URL you're being sent to is the one for logging in with forms authentication. It's actually complaining that it can't find the login page. Do you have authentication set for the folder?

Comment: No I wouldn't even know how to do that

Comment: It could be that the folder you've added doesn't have the right permissions set, so IIS is trying to log you in. Check that they're set up correctly, that would be my next guess.

Comment: I've just added 'Everyone' to the folder via IIS, same issue

Answer (score 0):

You're after umbracoReservedUrls instead.

umbracoReservedUrls

A comma-separated list of files to be left alone by Umbraco. IIS will serve these files, and the Umbraco request pipeline will not be triggered.

Comment: Thanks I tried that as well but same thing happened. - <add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/test/test.txt" />.. (I'm just editing the Web.config file on the FTP)

Comment: I've just tested this in an Umbraco v7.5.13 install and it worked fine so you have a permissions issue somewhere I think.

`<add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd,~/test/test.txt" />`